# How to create a File Gateway (Storage Gateway) in AWS using VPC Endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, gateway

I am trying to create an **AWS Storage Gateway for Files** under VPC Endpoint. Here is what I did:

- Selected **File Gateway** then Host Platform as **Amazon EC2**. (EC2 is with all necessary ports opened and assigned under same VPC in which I am going to create file gateway.)
- Then gave the DNS of VPC Endpoint and IP address of the EC2 for gateway VM.

And finally, when I tried to click CONNECT - it is giving me `INTERNAL ERROR`.

Can someone please correct me if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Faced with the same issue, just go direct to the gateway IP (without any additional request params in "Connect" button in wizard)

Comment: Or you pointed wrong vpc endpoint. It must be not vpce id , but fqdn 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/gateway-private-link.html#create-vpc-endpoint